# VB Validation keeps looping

Tags: vb.net

i have been assigned to write a program which saves data about films.We are required to use windows forms in vb.Im trying to validate the data entry for the text box.The text entered must be numbers and must be 4 characters long.The problem im trying to solve is that once it has looked at the value i want the program to allow the user to re-enter a value into the text box but instead it keeps looking at the text box with nothing in then says that it is not in the correct format , without letting the user enter a correct value.here is the code , just for the validation so far:

```
Dim PassValidate As Boolean = False
    ReadFilmData()
    NOFilms = NOFilms + 1
    ReDim Preserve Film(NOFilms)
    'Validate before it is saved to the file'
    Do
        If IsNumeric(Me.txtFilmID.Text) = True Then
            If Me.txtFilmID.TextLength = 0 Then
                'Presence check'
                MsgBox("You are required to provide a value for the film ID")
            ElseIf Me.txtFilmID.TextLength > 4 Then
                'Length Check'
                MsgBox("The film ID must be 4 numbers long")
            ElseIf Me.txtFilmID.TextLength = 4 Then
                PassValidate = True
            End If
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Me.txtFilmID.Text) = False Then
            MsgBox("The film ID must be a set of numbers ")
        End If
        If PassValidate = False Then
            txtFilmID.Text = ""
            MsgBox("Re-enter the value for Film ID")
            Call SaveFilmData()
        End If
        If PassValidate = True Then
            Film(NOFilms).FilmID = txtFilmID.Text
        End If
    Loop Until PassValidate = True
```

Comment: It keeps looping because it is a loop.  There is no chance for the user to re-enter or fix the errors

Comment: @Plutonix No, the loop has the condition "Loop Until PassValidate = True" !

Comment: You need to decide whether this is [tag:vba] or [tag:vb.net] - a VBA `UserForm` has very little to do with a VB.NET/WinForms `Form`. Looking at the `As Boolean = False` declaration this has to be .net code. That said you're initializing the Boolean to its default value, which is redundant.

Comment: Also you're using a LOT of VB6-ish functions and constructs. Remove the `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` instruction at the top of your module if you want to write idiomatic .net code.

Comment: But there is no need to loop at all.  The textlength for example will be the same each time unless and until the user has had a change to fix it

Comment: Put a beak point in, and step through your code. If the validation fails, the loop continues.

Answer (score 2):

you should check out the validation events in WinForms. They are there to avoid the very problem you are describing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Do Loop, there does not seem to be a need for the loop.